# Blender 4.0 bug? Object switch to transparent

Tags: 3d-view

Since I switched to Blender 4.0 I noticed that objects sometimes disappear depending on the viewing distance

very close: vanished or transparent in edit-dode
more distant: normal behaviour

The settings for clip start is 1 mm. Changing this doesn't solve the problem.
I copied the objects into a file with Blender 3.6: No problems here.

Is this an unidentified bug?

Comment: A screenshot (or two) would really be the way to get a diagnosis. There are many overlays, view modes, and gizmos that could cause things like that.

Comment: I can't say if it's a bug. I was having this problem. After an Internet search, I found an old post on here that unfortunately I can't find now. One of the answers to it solved it for me. If you are in perspective mode, try changing to orthographic mode and see if that helps.

Comment: If my above comment does what you want, you might want to go to Edit->Preferences->Navigation and turn off Auto Perspective under Orbit & Pan at the top of the section.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try removing one or two zeros in the viewport end clipping plane.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: I have already tried to expand or reduce the clipping plane. The main problem is that I installed v4.0 with the settings of 3.6 as usual. The problem does not occur in 3.6 with the identical *.blend file. Only when I open the blend file with 4.0 it does occur. At the moment I do not have access to the file, but I will try to remember it at home so that I can make it available to you.